# Link to a specific part of the page with top margin

Tags: html, css

The navigator of the page is not transparent. Every time when I link to a specific position of the page, some parts of the text will be hidden in the navigator. Shown as picture below:
[image]

What I want is:
[image]

You can see that in the first picture, the "background" is hidden inside the navigator.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    ul {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        opacity: 1.0;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0,0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        padding: 5px;
    }
    li {
        float: right;
    }
    li a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:hover {
        font-family: cursive;
    }

    h2 {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: Futura, Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: Brush Script MT, cursive;
    }

    h2, h3 {
      width: 50%;
      height: 60px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: inline;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <header id="header">
        <ul>  
          <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
          <li><a href="#background">Background</a></li>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </header>

      <!-- Home -->
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5", width="450", style="margin-top:100px">
      <tr id="home">
        <!--<section id="home"> -->
        <td>
            <div id="image">
                <img src="" style="margin:auto;width:150px;height:200px;display:block" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="section">
            <h2> sss  </h2>
            <h3>sss</h3>
                <p>ssssssss</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <!--</section>-->
      </tr>
        <!-- Background -->
      <tr id="background">
      <td colspan="2">
        <!--<section id="background">-->
            <div id="background1">
            <h2 style="font-family: Futura, Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;"> Background </h2>
            <p>Big Star was an American power pop band formed in Memphis, Tennessee, in 1971 by Alex Chilton, Chris Bell, Jody Stephens, and Andy Hummel. The group broke up in 1974, but reorganized with a new line-up nearly 20 years later. In its first era, the band's musical style drew on the vocal harmonies of The Beatles, as well as the swaggering rhythms of The Rolling Stones and the jangling guitars of The Byrds. To the resulting power pop, Big Star added dark, existential themes, and produced a style that foreshadowed the alternative rock of the 1980s and 1990s. Their first two albums, #1 Record and Radio City, suffered from ineffective marketing but garnered enthusiastic reviews; Rolling Stone called the band a "quintessential American power pop band" that was "one of the most mythic and influential cult acts in all of rock & roll". In 1993, Chilton and Stephens re-formed Big Star with Jon Auer and Ken Stringfellow. After tours in Europe and Japan, they released a new studio album, In Space, in 2005. Big Star was inducted into the Memphis Music Hall of Fame in 2014. (Full article...)Big Star was an American power pop band formed in Memphis, Tennessee, in 1971 by Alex Chilton, Chris Bell, Jody Stephens, and Andy Hummel. The group broke up in 1974, but reorganized with a new line-up nearly 20 years later. In its first era, the band's musical style drew on the vocal harmonies of The Beatles, as well as the swaggering rhythms of The Rolling Stones and the jangling guitars of The Byrds. To the resulting power pop, Big Star added dark, existential themes, and produced a style that foreshadowed the alternative rock of the 1980s and 1990s. Their first two albums, #1 Record and Radio City, suffered from ineffective marketing but garnered enthusiastic reviews; Rolling Stone called the band a "quintessential American power pop band" that was "one of the most mythic and influential cult acts in all of rock & roll". In 1993, Chilton and Stephens re-formed Big Star with Jon Auer and Ken Stringfellow. After tours in Europe and Japan, they released a new studio album, In Space, in 2005. Big Star was inducted into the Memphis Music Hall of Fame in 2014. (Full article...)
            Big Star was an American power pop band formed in Memphis, Tennessee, in 1971 by Alex Chilton, Chris Bell, Jody Stephens, and Andy Hummel. The group broke up in 1974, but reorganized with a new line-up nearly 20 years later. In its first era, the band's musical style drew on the vocal harmonies of The Beatles, as well as the swaggering rhythms of The Rolling Stones and the jangling guitars of The Byrds. To the resulting power pop, Big Star added dark, existential themes, and produced a style that foreshadowed the alternative rock of the 1980s and 1990s. Their first two albums, #1 Record and Radio City, suffered from ineffective marketing but garnered enthusiastic reviews; Rolling Stone called the band a "quintessential American power pop band" that was "one of the most mythic and influential cult acts in all of rock & roll". In 1993, Chilton and Stephens re-formed Big Star with Jon Auer and Ken Stringfellow. After tours in Europe and Japan, they released a new studio album, In Space, in 2005. Big Star was inducted into the Memphis Music Hall of Fame in 2014. (Full article...)
            Big Star was an American power pop band formed in Memphis, Tennessee, in 1971 by Alex Chilton, Chris Bell, Jody Stephens, and Andy Hummel. The group broke up in 1974, but reorganized with a new line-up nearly 20 years later. In its first era, the band's musical style drew on the vocal harmonies of The Beatles, as well as the swaggering rhythms of The Rolling Stones and the jangling guitars of The Byrds. To the resulting power pop, Big Star added dark, existential themes, and produced a style that foreshadowed the alternative rock of the 1980s and 1990s. Their first two albums, #1 Record and Radio City, suffered from ineffective marketing but garnered enthusiastic reviews; Rolling Stone called the band a "quintessential American power pop band" that was "one of the most mythic and influential cult acts in all of rock & roll". In 1993, Chilton and Stephens re-formed Big Star with Jon Auer and Ken Stringfellow. After tours in Europe and Japan, they released a new studio album, In Space, in 2005. Big Star was inducted into the Memphis Music Hall of Fame in 2014. (Full article...)
            </p>
            <hr>    
            </div>
        <!--</section>-->
      </td>
      </tr>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code on how you 'link to a specific position of the page'

Comment: I think it is `<a href="#background">Background</a>`

Comment: its hiding navigation bar because its position fixed , you can use it by jQuery

Comment: @ShibinRagh Could you please give a more detailed example?

Comment: Im not sure if you noticed.. you have 2 id="background"

Comment: @NormanBentley Sorry about that. I changed one. But I still have the problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer below.

Comment: did you manage to get the code working?

Comment: @NormanBentley Yes. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new class

```
.anchor { padding-top: 90px; }
```

And add this class to whichever element you want to link to. E.g.

```
<div id="background1" class="anchor">
```

Now when you link to this element, the class will automatically offset for you

Comment: I don't think this works. Could you please give an example?